# Python: modify variable stored as a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following situation:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> d = {"a": a}
>>> d
{'a': 1}
>>> d["a"] = 2
>>> d
{'a': 2}
>>> a
1
```

Of course this is the desired behaviour. However, when I assign 2 to the key `"a"` of the dictionary `d`, I would like to know if I can access the variable `a` instead of its value to modify the value of the variable `a` directly, accessing it through the dictionary. I.e. my expected last output would be

```
>>> a
2
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: This answer can help you to understand your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/15321776

Comment: @JorgeVerdeguerGómez that is very enlightening, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you know the idea of mutable and immutable objects. Immutable objects (str, int, float, etc) are passed by value. That's why your desired behaviour can't work. When you do:

```
a = 1 
d["a"] = a
```

you just pass the value of `a` variable to your dict key 'a'. `d['a']` knows nothing about variable `a`. They just both point to same primitive value in memory.

I don't know your case and why you need this behaviour, but you can try to use mutable object.
For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self._value = a

    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, a: int):
        # you can put some additional logic for setting new value
        self._value = a

    def __int__(self) -> int:
        return self._value
```

And then you can use it in this way:

```
>>> a = A(1)
>>> d = {"a": a}
>>> d['a'].value
1
>>> d["a"].value = 2
>>> d['a'].value
2
>>> a.value
2
>>> int(a)
2
```

But it still seems like an overhead and you should rethink whether you really need this behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

When you do

```
>>> a
```

, you are calling the value of the variable, `a` that you set on the first line. You have not changed the value of that variable, hence the output of `1`. If you did

```
>>> d["a"]
```

, your output would be

```
>>> 2
```

. If you want this value to be the variable `a`'s value too, set the value of `a` to the value of `d["a"]`.
Example-

```
>>> a = 1
>>> d = {"a": a}
>>> d
{'a': 1}
>>> d["a"] = 2
>>> d
{'a': 2}
>>> a = d["a"]
>>> a
2
```

Comment: While this provides the *output* that OP wants, it does not quite do what OP is trying to achieve